# Постраничный редирект на домен с www и https через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, ip, https, redirect

Здравствуйте.

Хочу чтобы, если пользователь ввёл домен с www или без, с http или https, ip или доменное имя, перенаправляло всегда на адрес вида [https://www.site.ru/путь](https://www.site.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C).
По отдельности решения нашёл, а, как всё объединить, не знаю.

Такой вариант переадресует с домена вида site.ru/путь на [https://www.site.ru/путь](https://www.site.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C). Но IP на домен не перенаправляет.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Подскажите, что нужно исправить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение, надо было добавить дополнительное условие на IP. Вроде работает как надо.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^62\.xxx\.xxx\.234$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^www].*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```